# How to set opacity/alpha in SpannableString Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin

How to actually set the alpha/opacity for spanned text using `SpannableStringBuilder` in Android? I want to achieve this design in one `TextView`:

[image]

The main text `Current location` have full opacity/alpha (1.0) and the sub text `Kungstan 43` have opacity of 84%.

I have set the `SpannableStringBuilder` as follows:

```
SpannableStringBuilder OriginText = new SpannableStringBuilder();
OriginText.Append(OriginMainText + ", ");
int SubTextIndex = OriginText.Length();
OriginText.Append(OriginSubText);
OriginText.SetSpan(<what need to set here??>, SubTextIndex, OriginText.Length(), 0)
```

What object should I put in `<what need to set here??>`? The closest approach is to set the foreground color but I prefer if it has way to set the alpha/opacity.

Comment: That's a rather simple design. You can achieve it even without opacity by simply changing the foreground color like you said.

Comment: @RacilHilan yes, it easier to just change the foreground but it will need me to define 2 different color rather than just 1 color with different opacity. That's why I said, I prefer if it has a way to set the alpha

Comment: Yes, but defining the same color with opacity is like defining 2 different colors :). You can see from my answer that it is not less work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TextAppearanceSpan`.

```
OriginText.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(...), SubTextIndex, OriginText.Length(), 0);
```

The syntax is:

```
TextAppearanceSpan(String family, 
                   int style, 
                   int size, 
                   ColorStateList color, 
                   ColorStateList linkColor)
```

The important parameter for you here is the `ColorStateList color`, which is defined like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_focused="true"
         android:color="@color/sample_focused" />
   <item android:state_pressed="true"
         android:state_enabled="false"
         android:color="@color/sample_disabled_pressed" />
   <item android:state_enabled="false"
         android:color="@color/sample_disabled_not_pressed" />
   <item android:color="@color/sample_default" />
</selector>
```

Starting with API 23, items may optionally define an `android:alpha` attribute to modify the base color's opacity, which is what you want. For example, the following item has 84% opacity as you wanted:

```
<item android:state_enabled="false"
      android:color="?android:attr/colorAccent"
      android:alpha="0.84" />
```

To get the color definition from resource, you can use:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to change the opacity is to concatenate the 2 digits representing the opacity to 6 digits representing the color, for example if the color is 0xFFFFFF, then the same color with half opacity (0x80) would be 0x80FFFFFF. Then use setSpan to  apply the color to a portion of text like so:

```
spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), ...)
```